# como validar si se establecio conexion con una Base de Datos usando Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

Se me hace necesario tener múltiples `Bases de Datos` en un sistema que estoy desarrollando. Hasta el momento he incluido la configuración en `config/database` como lo especifica la literatura de `laravel`

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'dump' => [
            'dump_binary_path' => 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
            'use_single_transaction',
            'timeout' => 60 * 10,
        ],
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
 
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],
```

Pero la Base de Datos `sqlsrv` a la cual deseo conectarme se encuentra en un servidor diferente y quisiera comprobar antes de hacer cualquier consulta en ella que este establecida la comunicación. Hasta el momento estoy usando como estas líneas de código:

```
$config = array(

    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'database' => 'sis_control',
    'host' => '10.25.20.29',
    'port' => '1433',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',

);

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::set('database.connections.mysql_dinamico',$config); // Asigno la DB que voy a usar

$conn = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection('mysql_dinamico'); //Asigno la nueva conexión al sistema.

if($conn) {

    return "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
    return "Conexión no establecida.<br />";
}
```

Pero todo el tiempo el resultado es `Conexión establecida`; aun cuando pongo valores falseados que no se corresponden a la conexión.

Alguna idea de como pudiera validar si esta establecida la conexión o no???

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución a mi problema. La dejo por si alguien la necesita:

```
$config = array(

    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'sis_control',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '3306',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
);

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::set('database.connections.mysql_dinamico',$config);
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection('mysql_dinamico');

try {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection('mysql_dinamico')->getPdo();
    echo "Conectado satisfactoriamente: " . \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection('mysql_dinamico')->getDatabaseName();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die("No es posible conectarse a la Base de Datos. Por favor, revise su configuración." );
}
```